# Solving the congruence relation $90\equiv 6 \pmod n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

A family member of mine is currently taking high school Algebra 2 and is learning about the basics of modular arithmetic. The following question was asked of the students:

---

Find all integers *n* that satisfy the following:

$90\equiv 6 \pmod n$

---

The family member asked me for help, as she was stuck. But I too was stumped. It has been two years since I took Algebra 2, and I barely remember modular arithmetic. I seem to remember that $90\equiv 6 \pmod n$ means that 90 mod *n* = 6 mod *n* -- however, I am not sure how that can help me solve the problem.

I know this is a rather elementary question so I apologize if it has already been answered. That said, I have not been able to find an answer so far, as most sources deal with equations where the unknown value is something *other* than the one "inside" the mod parenthesis.

Comment: $90\equiv6\pmod n$  means $n$ divides $90-6$

Comment: The definition is surely given in their textbook. What does it say?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don't think they *have* a textbook, alas...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$90\equiv6\pmod n$  means $n$ divides $90-6,$ so the solutions for $n$ are the factors of $84.$

Comment: Thanks! Why does it mean n divides 90 - 6, though?

Comment: That's the definition, so $90=qn+r$ and $6=pn+r$ where $0\le r<n$